# Не корректная работа transform-style: preserve-3d в IE10-11

Tags: css3, internet-explorer, transform

Здравствуйте.
Опять IE не дает покоя...
В нормальных браузерах куб отображается нормально. В IE все стороны падают в одну плоскость. И получается что вращается одна картинка, а не куб как задумано.

Код https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YxPYrw

Pug:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
html(lang="en")
head
    meta(charset="UTF-8")
    title Document
    link(rel="stylesheet", href="style/style.css")
body
    #box
        .box
            .cube.g-spinner
                .cube__front.g-font
                .cube__back.g-font
                .cube__top.g-font
                .cube__bottom.g-font
                .cube__left.g-font
                .cube__right.g-font
    .footer
        input(type="button" value="left").js-btnLeft
        input(type="button" value="right").js-btnRight

script(src="script/script.js")
```

Sass

```
body
    padding: 100px
    background-color: #222
    color: #FFF
    display: flex
    flex-direction: column
    justify-content: center
#box
    position: relative
    height: auto
    margin-bottom: 400px

.box
    perspective: 800px
    perspective-origin: 50% 100px

.cube
    position: relative
    width: 200px
    margin: 0 auto
    transform-style: preserve-3d
    &__back
        transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateY(180deg)
        background: url(../img/superman.jpg) no-repeat
        background-size: 100% 100%
    &__right
        transform: rotateY(-270deg) translateX(100px)
        transform-origin: top right
        background: url(../img/deadstroke.jpg) no-repeat
        background-size: 100% 100%
    &__left
        transform: rotateY(270deg) translateX(-100px)
        transform-origin: center left
        background: url(../img/deadshot.jpg) no-repeat
        background-size: 100% 100%
    &__top
        transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateY(-100px)
        transform-origin: top center
        background: url(../img/gl.jpg) no-repeat
        background-size: 100% 100%
    &__bottom
        transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(100px)
        transform-origin: bottom center
        background: url(../img/am.jpg) no-repeat
        background-size: 100% 100%
    &__front
        transform: translateZ(100px)
        background: url(../img/batman.jpg) no-repeat
        background-size: 100% 100%
.footer
    display: flex
    flex-direction: row
    justify-content: center

.g-font
    position: absolute
    width: 200px
    height: 200px
    line-height: 200px
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.55)
.g-spinner
    transform: rotateY(0deg)
```

JS(Смысловой нагрузки не несет только отвечает за кнопки и вращение куба)

```
window.onload = () =>{
    const spin = document.getElementsByClassName('g-spinner')[0],
        btnLeft = document.getElementsByClassName('js-btnLeft')[0],
        btnRight = document.getElementsByClassName('js-btnRight')[0];
    let i = 0;

let spiner = setInterval(function(){
    if(i < 360){
        i++;
        spin.style.transform = `rotateY(${i}deg)`;
    }else{
        i=0;
    }
},10);

let completeSpinLeft = (max, i) => {
    let b = 0 + i;
        b = max - b;
    for(b; b--;){
        i++;
        spin.style.transform = `rotateY(${i}deg)`;
    }
}

let completeSpinRight = (max, i) => {
    let b = 0 + i - max;

    for(b; b--;){
        i--;
        spin.style.transform = `rotateY(${i}deg)`;
    }
}


let breakSpinToLeft = () =>{
    clearInterval(spiner);
    if((i > 0) && (i < 90)){
        completeSpinLeft(90, i);
    }
    if((i > 90) && (i < 180)){
        completeSpinLeft(180, i);
    }
    if((i > 180) && (i < 270)){
        completeSpinLeft(270, i);
    }
    if((i > 270) && (i < 360)){
        completeSpinLeft(360, i);
    }
}

let breakSpinToRight = () =>{
    clearInterval(spiner);
    if((i > 0) && (i < 90)){
        completeSpinRight(270, 360);
    }
    if((i > 90) && (i < 180)){
        completeSpinRight(1, i);
    }
    if((i > 180) && (i < 270)){
        completeSpinRight(90, i);
    }
    if((i > 270) && (i < 360)){
        completeSpinRight(180, i);
    }

}
    btnLeft.addEventListener('click', breakSpinToLeft);
    btnRight.addEventListener('click', breakSpinToRight);
}
```

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=transform-style

Comment: Может есть библиотека которая подключит поддержку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отказался полностью от `preserve-3d` и переписал код под:

```
transform: perspective() rotateY() translateZ();
```